# Pagination script style current page number after click on next/ previous buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a pagination script (code below); and I don't know how to select the current pagination number after clicking on the next previous buttons (I have added a comment to the missing bit below: `removeClass('current');` and `addClass('current') to active pagination number;` ).  The style should work the same as directly clicking on the page number `$("#pagin li a").click(function()...`

here is a picture:

[pagination style when current page selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I4gn.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
pageSize = 4;
incremSlide = 5;
startPage = 0;
numberPage = 0;

var pageCount =  $(".browsethearchive-items").length / pageSize;
var totalSlidepPage = Math.floor(pageCount / incremSlide);
    
for(var i = 0 ; i<pageCount;i++){
    $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a></li> ');
    if(i>pageSize){
       $("#pagin li").eq(i).hide();
    }
}

var prev = $("<li/>").addClass("prev").html("Prev").click(function(){
   startPage-=1;
   incremSlide-=1;
   numberPage--;
   slide();
});

prev.hide();

var next = $("<li/>").addClass("next").html("Next").click(function(){
   startPage+=1;
   incremSlide+=1;
   numberPage++;
   slide();
});


$("#pagin").prepend(prev).append(next);

$("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current");

slide = function(sens){
   $("#pagin li").hide();
   
   for(t=startPage;t<incremSlide;t++){
     $("#pagin li").eq(t+1).show();
   }
   if(startPage == 0){
     next.show();
     prev.hide();
   }else if(numberPage == totalSlidepPage ){
     next.hide();
     prev.show();
   }else{
     next.show();
     prev.show();
   }
   
    
}

showPage = function(page) {
      $(".browsethearchive-items").hide();
      $(".browsethearchive-items").each(function(n) {
          if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
              $(this).show();
      });        
}
    
showPage(1);
$("#pagin li a").eq(0).addClass("current");


var $listItems = $('#pagin li a');
var activeLink;


$("#pagin li a").click(function() {

    $listItems.removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');  
    var activeLink=$(this);

    showPage(parseInt($(this).text()));
});


var i = 1;

$(".prev").click(function() {

    // removeClass('current');
    // addClass('current') to active pagination number; 

    if (i != 1) {
      showPage(--i);
    }
});
$(".next").click(function() {

    // removeClass('current');
    // addClass('current') to active pagination number; 


    if (i < ($('.browsethearchive-items').length)/4) {
      showPage(++i);
    }    
});
```

*UPDATE* here is a fiddle with the working code — > https://jsfiddle.net/JoChicau/em19ku8v/39/ — > thanks to @biberman!

Comment: Move the code that handles which page link is `current` into the `showPage` function then you already have it as `$("#pagin li").eq(i).hide()` -> `$("#pagin li").removeClass("active").eq(page).addClass("active")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the list element with the class "current" in this way:

```
$("#pagin li a.current")
```

For setting the class "current" to the next or previous list element you can use the jQuery methods `next()` and `prev()`. Since you set the class to the anchor inside the list element you first have to select the parent of the anchor with the `parent()` function to get the list element itself and after using `next()` or `prev()` select the anchor inside the new list element with `find("a")`.

**Working example**:

```js
$(".prev").click(function() {
  let prevLi = $("#pagin li a.current").parent().prev().find("a");
  if (prevLi[0]) {
    $("#pagin li a.current").removeClass("current");
    prevLi.addClass("current");
  }
});

$(".next").click(function() {
  let nextLi = $("#pagin li a.current").parent().next().find("a");
  if (nextLi[0]) {
    $("#pagin li a.current").removeClass("current");
    nextLi.addClass("current");
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:not(.next, .prev) {
  background-color: grey;
}

li a.current {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="pagin">
    <li class="prev"><</li>
    <li><a class="current">1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>
    <li><a>5</a></li>
    <li class="next">></li>
</ul>
```

---

Additionally i would recommend to add and remove the classes directly to/from the li tag because it makes the script a bit easier (for example no need for `parent()` and `find("a")`).

**Working example**:

```js
$(".prev").click(function() {
    let prevLi = $("#pagin li.current").prev();
    if (prevLi.find('a')[0]) {
        $("#pagin li.current").removeClass("current");
        prevLi.addClass("current");
    }
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    let nextLi = $("#pagin li.current").next();
    if (nextLi.find('a')[0]) {
        $("#pagin li.current").removeClass("current");
        nextLi.addClass("current");  
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

li:not(.next, .prev) {
    background-color: grey;
}

li.current {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="pagin">
    <li class="prev"><</li>
    <li class="current"><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>
    <li><a>5</a></li>
    <li class="next">></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi! I couldnt make your last edit work, but the previous code works:
```
var i = 1;

$(".prev").click(function() {
    let prevLi = $("#pagin li a.current").parent().prev().find("a");
    $("#pagin li a.current").removeClass("current");
    prevLi.addClass("current");

    if (i != 1) {
      showPage(--i);
    }
});

```
and the equivalent for the next button:

Comment: $(".next").click(function() {

    let nextLi = $("#pagin li a.current").parent().next().find("a");
    $("#pagin li a.current").removeClass("current");
    nextLi.addClass("current");

    if (i < ($('.browsethearchive-items').length)/ pageSize) {
      showPage(++i);
    }  
});

Comment: this code is used to move to the prev/next page while sliding left/right the pagination; problem I have perhaps to do with the larger bit of code is that when next and prev buttons are clicked they move +1 page sequentially but if I clicked a page a bit further ahead it does not go +1 from there..

Comment: What is not working - the pagination or the showPage() function? Or is ```if(nextLi[0])``` and  ```if(prevLi[0])``` not working?

Comment: your last edit does not work with my structure as I am using this on the HTML: 
<ul id="pagin" class="browsethearchive-pagination">
         
</ul>

so the content in between including <li>  is generated by the script above; the original post you made though worked well, only that it moves +1 page sequentially so if I click a page number for eg. +2 ahead it does not go +1 from there but back from where it was last clicked 'next' or 'prev'..  probably as you are saying it is an error with my  showPage() function?

Comment: Do you mean with "last edit" the second example or do you mean that i did also change the code for the first example? If it's the latter then unfortunately i don't know what it was before. Since i still not understand what is not working, i want to know if the solution for the original question (next/prev) is not working or something else. If it is the latter then it should be asked in a new question ;)>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232233/discussion-between-biberman-and-user15885108).

Answer (score -1):

*Warning: below code is untested.*

Set an id containing the page number on every `<a>` representing a page. For instance

```js
$("#pagin").append(`<li><a href="#" id="page-${i}">${i+1}</a></li> `);
```

Then use this id to target the right `<a>`

```js
$(".prev").click(function() {
    if (i != 1) {
        i--;
        $listItems.removeClass('current');
        $(`#pagin li a#page-${i}`).addClass('current');

        showPage(i);
    }
});
```